# Platform event - not accessible through LMA

Tags: apex, api, platform-event, licenses, fls

On one of the org. I got the below error from the Platform event

*Access to entity 'Log__e' denied: Entity is not api accessible common.exception.ApiException: Access to entity 'Log__e' denied'*

This error occurred from LMA (license management app) during the creation of the lead.

So during the creation of lead, a trigger is called which then calls Log__e platform event.

For normal users, it works fine, but for LMA the task is automatically running and not by a user.

What could be an issue here?

Thanks in advance!